# Get transaction id when using neo4j Bolt drivers (Python or Java)?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-java-api, neo4j-python-driver

I'm trying to build a REST API to hide the complexity of Cypher from the user who will use my program building simple and high-level API calls to interact with the Neo4j Graph.
I want to give the user the possibility to work with transactions like in [HTTP API](https://neo4j.com/docs/http-api/3.5/introduction/) (open a transaction, execute statements in a transaction, commit/rollback a transaction), using a **transaction id**.
It is possible to extract the transaction id from transactions created using one of the official Bolt drivers?

Answer (score 0):

You could just create your own unique ID (e.g., a [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)) for each transaction, and maintain a mapping between those IDs to the active transactions.